# Android emm device owner connect to wifi network

Tags: android, android-enterprise, emm, android-enterprise-features

As an android developer who currently is working on an EMM client I want to silently connect device to wifi network. I have device owner privilege but still need to show user a prompt and wait for user acceptance.

Because I am device owner of a manged device, Is there any way of doing this? I couldn't find any related API in android device policy manager.